# Joining tables to get the number of occurences with another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I've got 2 tables. One is called `subscriptions` and the other is called `service_sushi_service`.
I am trying to get all of the phones which have more than 2 different `service_id`.
for example.

```
phone: 12345 service id: 12 
phone: 12345 service id: 12 
phone: 12345 service id: 8
phone: 12345 service id: 8
phone: 12345 service id: 13
phone: 22222 service id: 13
phone: 22333 service id: 3
```

I need to output it as phone=12345, occurences=3

This is what I got so far: and I have no idea how to go further.

```
SELECT 
    `sub`.`phone` AS `phone`
FROM 
    `subscriptions` AS `sub`
LEFT JOIN `service_sushi_service` `sushi_service` ON `sushi_service`.`sushi_service_id` = `sub`.`sushi_service_id`
WHERE 
    date(`sub`.`added`) >= '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY `sub`.`phone`
```

Comment: Can you please add the table structures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    `sub`.`phone` AS `phone`,
    COUNT(`sushi_service`.`sushi_service_id`) as occurences        
FROM 
    `subscriptions` AS `sub`
LEFT JOIN `service_sushi_service` `sushi_service` ON `sushi_service`.`sushi_service_id` = `sub`.`sushi_service_id`
WHERE 
    date(`sub`.`added`) >= '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY `sub`.`phone`
HAVING occurences > 2
```

EDIT: <del>Should point out that HAVING seems to be a MySQL only kinda thing</del>. Thought I'd post this for your reference - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: Good solution (inner join could be used though) although the having clause needs to be _HAVING whatever > 2_

Comment: at least postgres as of 8.2 and oracle 11gR2 also support the having clause (cf. [here(postgres)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/features-sql-standard.html) and [here(oracle)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2078943)). furthermore it's part of the current sql standard.

Comment: `HAVING` is not a mysql-only kinda thing. It's part of the SQL 92 standard ([see more on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_%28SQL%29))

Answer (score 3):

Two things I see with this code:

1. Why are you doing `LEFT JOIN`?  I'd say you need a straight `INNER JOIN`.
2. You can use `count(distinct field_name)` to get the corresponding value.

Hence the SQL can look like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    `sub`.`phone` AS `phone`,
     count(distinct `sushi_service`.`sushi_service_id`) as `occurrences`
FROM 
    `subscriptions` AS `sub`
JOIN `service_sushi_service` `sushi_service` ON `sushi_service`.`sushi_service_id` = `sub`.`sushi_service_id`
WHERE 
    date(`sub`.`added`) >= '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY `sub`.`phone`
HAVING `occurrences` > 2
```

Comment: count(distinct field_name) love this

Answer (score 1):

No need for joins at all

```
select s1.phone, count(s1.*) from 
    (select unique phone, sushi_service_id from subscriptions) s1
group by s1.phone having count(s1.*) > 2
```

Comment: a join is much more efficient than a subselect

Comment: no solution without a join will work unless subscription info from the `subscriber` table is replicated in `service_sushi_service`, the latter being not advisable since such a db schema is not normalized. you may substitute subselects for an explicit join but effectively you're just imitating the join operator for your query.